# Excel / Printer issue

Tags: microsoft-excel, printer

I have a client who has an Excel workbook with some formulas built in to it. The idea is you need to select a value and depending on the value selected from the drop down cells become populated with data. When he prints to a specific printer it prints all the cells even the ones "hidden" when you select the values that don't populate cells. I've pinpointed the issue to the one printer he uses as the other printers won't print the hidden data. Is there something else I should be on the lookout for? A specific setting perhaps in the printer or the book?

Google-ing only came up with answers on conditional formatting and how to deselect certain cells from printing but that's not what I need.

Comment: Have you tried updating the printer drivers?

Comment: Spell out how you fixed it/it was fixed post it as the answer below. In a couple days you'll get to mark it as the accepted answer. That can help others with similar issues.

Comment: The print drivers were all recently updated. Sorry I forgot to include that tidbit. Fixed the issue either way... 

When the client initially approached me I asked if any sort of formatting was done conditional or otherwise... The answer was no so I disregarded that. Fast forward to today I decided to look for myself and sure enough there was conditional formatting applied. followed the steps in this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247803/conditional-formatting-to-hide-cell-content-even-when-printed and the issue was resolved.

Moral of the story:  Never trust the client!

Comment: Sorry hit enter prematurely before I finished the post. Above is the completed post with the link to my fix. Thanks for your help though Music2myear!

Comment: No kidding on that "never trust the client" bit. Another way to say it is "always ask twice, then ask 'are you sure', then look over their shoulder anyway".

Comment: Well, we can't close this as duplicate because that solution is on a different site. But, under the "Your Answer" section you can post how you found the user had misinformed you, and then the steps you followed to fix it. It just helps us see there is a fix for this issue, and as these results come up in Google quite a bit, it'll help others with the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the following are steps I took to resolve the issue...

1) For whatever reason I decided to check for any macros or conditional formatting just to be on the safe side. Call it a hunch. Needless to say there was infact conditional formatting applied.

2) After finding out that someone applied conditional formatting not taking into account color schemes I now google'd how to tweak it (I am terrible with Excel)

3) I stumbled upon this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247803/conditional-formatting-to-hide-cell-content-even-when-printed and followed user mpalanco's answer which resolved the issue for the client.

4) It's also important to note that I used the color white for all the cells that were conditionally formatted. That tidbit was posted by someone else below the user who posted the answer.

I tried to copy the answer into my post for reference and ease of use but I don't have enough rep points yet to post images. I hope this helps anyone else having this issue.

Comment: Thanks. I selected the checkmark and its now a green icon.